# What does "echo" mean when it comes to using Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I'm currently learning how to use Maven and have encountered a term called "echo". I was just wondering what it actually means?

> There are few important concepts related to Maven Lifecycles, which
>   are worth to mention:
>
> 1) When a phase is called via Maven command, for example mvn compile,
>   only phases up to and including that phase will execute.
>
> 2) Different maven goals will be bound to different phases of Maven
>   lifecycle depending upon the type of packaging (JAR / WAR / EAR).
>
> In the following example, we will attach maven-antrun-plugin:run goal
>   to few of the phases of Build lifecycle. This will allow us to **echo
>   text messages** displaying the phases of the lifecycle.

Comment: Please replace the image with text, not everyone can see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[echo](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html) is an ant task which allow to print messages to console (system.out)

This makes sense when using maven-antrun-plugin which allow to execute ant tasks in a maven build.

It can be used to print some maven properties during the build as there is no built-in way to output value to console in maven.

```
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.antrun.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo>Configuration properties :</echo>
                            <echo>service.endpoint=${service.endpoint}</echo>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! its tough to be a beginner, but so lucky to have people like you helping out!

Answer (score 1):

It means to use `echo` tag in ant script executed by `maven-antrun-plugin:run`. Nothing directly related to maven itself.